# Novel about Immortals hiding from the world

Tags: story-identification, novel, immortality

I'm looking for a book I read as a kid in the 80's, I want to say it takes place in a resort in Mexico where a group of Immortals meet including Nefertiti and end up tracked/attacked by the government who wants to capture them and study them so they can make others immortal. I want to say that the main character was a younger immortal, but it's been so long I can't remember for sure if that was right or not. Sadly that's all the details I have but I remember the book having a reddish cover with picture of the famous bust of Nefertiti on it among other things that I just can't remember.

[edit]The book I read was a paperback and was in English, sadly I can't remember any more details about it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Don't forget to include details that might seem obvious such as language, hardback/paperback, anything you might remember about the cover, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for, but the desciption partly fits Alfred Bester's [*The Computer Connection.*](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Connection-Alfred-Bester-ebook/dp/B0037Z70SK/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) Part of the book takes place in the in the deserts of the American soutwest, IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

[image]"Eternity" by Mack Reynolds (finished after Reynold's death by Dean Ing.

What was the secret of San Raphael? It held too many faces from the past. Alex Germain recognized a former lover..then a noted intellectual..and a handsome, courtly Italian. All as young, as vital, as when Alex had first met them--decades earlier. Alex demanded the truth..but he had nothing to do with the murders that began to strike San Raphael. Suddenly the little Mexican village crackled with violence. Battle had been joined. To the losers: nothing but death. To the winners: eternity.  The cover shows a Nefertti-looking woman in the background.  I recognized the plotline as being one of their collaborations and Google did the rest.

[the cover](https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/N-4AAOSwkl5XfGOz/s-l225.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Is it The Immortals By James Gunn?

https://sciencefictionruminations.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/book-review-the-immortals-james-e-gunn-1962/

Comment: I'm pretty sure Nefertiti doesn't come up in *The Immortals*.